# Our Unofficial Facebook page

Tags: discussion

Hi Guys here is our Unofficial Facebook page

[Hinduism Stackexchange Page Link](https://www.facebook.com/hinduism.stackexchange/info)

This is just for the purposes of increasing our traffic, so please help to make it popular by spreading it to your friends. There is no restriction setting, so anybody can post it there.

Every suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Awesome Idea... But should've started after the site entered public beta

Comment: @Mr.Alien agreed. but some users in chat room, including me, decided to create this page now itself.

Comment: I think people won't get a way to create their account, post that for a while, submit your email id if they want an invitation to join private beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few suggestions:

- Its name should be plain Hinduism and in about it should contain link to our main site.
- we can set rss feed for our main site questions there.
- Unofficial word should be there to not confuse it with SE property.

Comment: +1 for adding rss feed of main site on facebook page.