# One year completed, where do we stand?

Tags: discussion, moderators, site-promotion

Hinduism community has completed [One Year](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/happy-one-year-anniversary) recently and hopefully will make into graduation sooner or later.

But this could be a good point to start thinking where do we stand?

Our [Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) are:-

[image]

Shows clearly that our visitors are not less but the participation is lesser. That doesn't means we need to stop promoting our site but to focus more on gathering good content. Spread about our site among your friends. We already have social network promotion pages in [Facebook](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/our-unofficial-facebook-page) and [Twitter](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/twitter-page-for-hinduism-se-promotion), you just need to share this link among your friends. Feel free for giving suggestions for this pages. We can also use [Community promotion ads](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376/why-we-never-tried-our-hand-in-community-promotion-ads) for inter SE site promotion.

**Now What else can we do?**

It's not that we have ended up with question but we have stopped asking them. Don't feel shy in asking them or answering them.

**Point To Improve**:

- Meta participation
- Handling [Review bar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review)
- Usage of chat for clarification or even support
- Edits, vote and flag

**@Moderator**: I hope some events can also be helpful like [Topic of the week](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/topic-of-the-week) or something like Mythology ([Mythology of the month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/monthly-mythology-reading-group-would-you-be-interested)) or Buddhism ([Book of the month](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/choosing-a-book-for-book-of-the-month-june)). With the help of high rep user we can also opt for some best answer bounty reward even monthly, will love to help with that. Increase in usage of Community bulletin to highlight meta post which need attention. Re-election request to high lords if old mods are opting out. <sup>Nothing personal to anyone.</sup>

At last Hinduism is the third largest religion on basis of followers, so we can atleast make into a graduate site over a stack exchange network. And request all user to keep it friendly for everyone from curios outsider to a strict follower.

Feel free for any kind of suggestion, we as a SE community can together make it possible.

Comment: Nice one Ankit. I can't see much participation on this site though the site is Becoming popular. I suggest whoever is active should present themselves by commenting below. So that we know who is active.

Comment: @Mr_Green [something like this](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/322/who-are-you-and-why-are-you-here) you suggest?

Comment: That's a good idea. In a way, that's an improvement of my thought.

Comment: out of the 24% that are not answered, atleast 10% are actually answered but not marked so, and another 5% will probably never be answered for years (This is because they were asked by the expert @KeshavSrinivasan and there is no-one else on this site at the moment with such vast knowledge). but alas, this is not taken into account :).

Comment: @Sai Thanks for the kind words.  Yeah, I'm single-handedly bringing down the answered question percentage, because I've posted over 10% of the total questions on the site!  By the way, I actually have a long list of questions I want to ask, which keeps getting bigger, and every so often I take one of the questions on the list, do research to try to answer it, and then post it on the site.

Comment: questions per day is **ok** now there is 5.1 !

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One Suggestion If you can just delete the questions which are not required like the cow question you recently posted which is likely not to have answers, and is obsolete nowadays as purva mimansakas are extinct.http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11751/what-scriptures-say-that-the-cows-of-the-gods-walk-on-their-backs

Comment: @Yogi Well, hopefully my questions will get answers as the site grows  and we get more experts.  And high-level questions like mine serve the purpose of attracting experts to the site.  The fact that the Purva Mimamsa school is extinct doesn't make my question obsolete; Purva Mimamsa is still a subject of scholarly study.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few suggestions for increasing participation, though I do not know if they can be implemented.
1. We could have a shloka posted each day (or maybe once a week) in Sanskrit, along with its transliteration in English followed by the translation. If we happen to choose really difficult ones, it could lead to more people asking questions about them.
2. From what I have found when I tried to introduce this site to my friends (who aren't experts, nor am I) is they do not know where to begin. They found the long answers and numerous references intimidating. It would be helpful to have a Hinduism Blog where the major scriptures and their major points are discussed, something like Wikipedia, but in simpler terms, and brief, with links to the answers on this site.
3. As Hinduism is a way of life, I feel we should encourage more questions about the various customs that are followed around the country. People will be more willing to talk about what they know if they don't have to cite scriptural references all the time. This way we will have a collection of the various customs, folklore and the experts can provide the references wherever possible.
This last point could be integrated with what Ankit Sharma discussed in Topic of the week. 
I personally feel that the Book of the Month idea is excellent! We too should do something like that.