# Book of the Month

Tags: discussion

With reference to [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/one-year-completed-where-do-we-stand), would it be acceptable if I pick a text and started asking questions related to it? I was looking forward to the "Book of the month" idea materializing on this site, but sadly, it's still an idea. Being a person who is reading a sacred text for the first time, how much support do I stand to get from the experts here if I were to initiate it? How would all the users be notified of such an event happening? 
If there are users who agree, I would like to propose Bhagavata Purana to be the book of this month.

Comment: We can share such things on meta, I don't think its a good idea to post such questions on the main site

Comment: @Mr.Alien he doesn't said to post this on main meta but its like Topic of week, where people decide to pick a book to be discussed and that will be base for the question over main site. Like combine reading and asking doubts .

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't think you got his question or i think you didn't got what I was trying to say

Comment: Firstly, Suhasini is a girl's name :) Secondly, @Mr.Alien, I do not want to post this question on the main site. As Ankit Sharma explained, I want to pick a particular book and ask questions based on it. I want to know if there is a better way of informing the users about it other than posting on the meta site because many users do not visit the meta site as often.

Comment: @Suhasini That's what I just replied in my previous comment, that the only way to inform the users for book of the month thingy, you should post it on meta and not the main site :)

Comment: Also when I said SUCH QUESTIONS doesn't mean this question but the book of the month type questions.. I hope it clears the doubt

Comment: @Mr.Alien, okay :) Couldn't we send out a message to all users in the weekly newsletter? Or something like that so that word would reach everyone?

Comment: @Suhasini umm, can you give me a day or two to figure out a decent solution for this? idea is kinda great but we also need an equally good execution plan

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, that is very true :) Take as long as you need.

Comment: @Suhasini i think the only available option is a "community event". It will appear above community bulletin with remaining day timer. [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjynk.png)

Comment: @AnkitSharma, that is a good option!