# Would it be a good idea to hold community events on festivals?

Tags: discussion, community-events

In the post,
[One year completed, where do we stand?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/one-year-completed-where-do-we-stand), a diamond moderator had mentioned that holding events can be a good idea to spread information about the site. Would it be a good idea to hold a few chat events on major Hindu festivals?

We can use these events to spread knowledge about that particular festival to other users, who are unaware of those. The advantage is that, the events are shown atop the chat main page. Hence other non users of the site can also join in.

<sub>Note: Moderators can create [community events](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/admin/community-events) and it'll be pinned to the top of the CB. In this way any user of the site will get to know about it.</sub>

Comment: Sound like a good idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've just started one event (community event as well as [chat event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295936/260388)) on the festival of Ganesha Chaturthi.

Brief information: You can read about Ganesha Chaturthi on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_Chaturthi). It starts on Bhadrapada Shukla Chaturthi i.e on 25 Aug for current year and usually holds for 10 days. People celebrates this festival in home as well as in public. They install new Mutri (idol) of Ganesha at home or in society and worship everyday for 10 days and then Visarjana (immersing of idol in water) is carried out.

However we're somewhat late in starting event, The community event is started on 26 August at 8pm IST and will last for 10 days i.e upto 5<sup>th</sup> September . Talking about chat-event, it will be happened during 8pm to 11pm IST everyday for 10 days on the [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism). You can register yourself [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15189/hinduism?tab=schedule).

One can find community event in Community Bulletin i.e at the right (side) panel on main as well as on meta site and chat event at [chat.SE main page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

[image]

---

After experimenting this event we can get an idea regarding how such events can be useful and also about community's interest in.

Upon the suggestion from users in community, we'll carryout events on such important festivals.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: A Navaratri chat event for this year was [planned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUiaC.png) and scheduled today from 10 AM to 1 PM (IST) on [Hinduism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) which has deemed effective -- more than 10+ users actively participated for more than three hours :)

You can find transcript for [18 Oct. 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15189/2018/10/18)

---

<sup>Note: From [previous](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/929/277) event we found out that events would be effective on weekends.</sup>

**Navaratri** starts from tomorrow! And will end on 29 Sept. Dussehara (Vijayadashami) is on 30<sup>th</sup> Sept.

- Chat event for Navaratri is scheduled on this weekend i.e 23<sup>th</sup> & 24<sup>th</sup> (Saturday & Sunday) Sept. at 8-11 pm (IST).
- In the next weekend (30<sup>th</sup> Sept. and 1<sup>st</sup> Oct.) chat event will be scheduled for Navaratri/Dussehara/Vijayadashami.

You can find and register for chat events at [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15189/hinduism?tab=schedule).